# Split string according to occurrence of a character

Tags: r, substr

My task is to split and extract the part from a string until the occurrence of the fourth underscore.
I am working with R right now but I am kind of a beginner with programming and stuff.

The input looks like this:

```
6_10_36_0_1
6_10_38_16_15
6_100_76_16_18.1
```

My required result would look like this:

```
6_10_36_0
6_10_38_16
6_100_76_16
```

My idea is the following:

```
substr(data$x, 0, XXX)
```

While XXX defines the position before the fourth underscore, maybe using grep or strsplit?

Sorry, if I asked a stupid and easy-to-answer question. However I didn't find a fitting to answers already posted.

---

edit:

```
> bestand$ID<-sub("(_[0-9.]+$)", "", bestand$x)
Fehler in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "ID", value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 36513
> gsub("(_[0-9.]+$)", "", "6_100_63_8_2")
[1] "6_100_63_8"
>
```

apparently the command works, however it doesnot work with the matrix..

Comment: it looks like your `bestand` data frame doesn't actually have an `x` component?  What is the result of `names(bestand)`, or even better `str(bestand)` [if `bestand` doesn't have a huge number of rows]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stringr` [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) has lots of handy shortcuts for this kind of work:

```
# input data   
data <- read.table(text = "6_10_36_0_1
6_10_38_16_15
6_100_76_16_18.1")

# load library
library(stringr)

# prepare regular expression
regexp <- "([[:digit:]]+_){3}[[:digit:]]+"

# process string
(str_extract(data$V1, regexp))
```

Which gives the desired result:

```
[1] "6_10_36_0"   "6_10_38_16"  "6_100_76_16"
```

To explain the `regexp` a little:

`[[:digit:]]` is any number 0 to 9

`+` means the preceding item (in this case, a digit) will be matched one or more times

`_` is the underscore, as is

`{3}` means repeat the previous string three times

This page is also very useful for this kind of string processing: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing

Comment: How about `regexp <- "([[:digit:]]+_){3}[[:digit:]]+"`?  It seems to give the correct result and is at least slightly easier to type ...

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expression to replace with null, in php we do

```
$string = '6_10_36_0_1';
$newstring =preg_replace('/(_[0-9.]+$)/', '', $string);
```

Edit (I dono exactly about r but roughly it would be like this)

```
sub("(_[0-9.]+$)", "", 'your strings or array of strings')

gsub("(_[0-9.]+$)", "", 'your strings or array of strings')
```

and the tutorial is [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer! i tried to use your line in R but didnot succeed. Do you know the corresponding command in R?

Comment: for `r` i think sub() and gsub() @user1918745